# Composer screenshot in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is there a way to do a screenshot of the composer in QGIS?

I am regularly doing maps in a rush to insert in reports or presentation and it could save time if I would not have to save them and then import them in the report/presentation.

In addition it would allow not to store plenty of draft maps.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

If doing `composer / export as image` is too long, you can always use a tool like [`Snipping Tool`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots) with a fixed size.

From experience, I found it is worth to take the extra time to record every image embedded in any document, along with the parameters used to generate them, as someone inevitably ask, months later, to make a simple modification that takes forever when starting from scratch again.

Comment: Lots of options for this. I personally use Cropper. https://cropper.codeplex.com/ Copies to clipboard or file.

Comment: Press PnSc Button on keyboard, paste and crop the image

Comment: Thank you for your answers, however I forget to mention I don't want to use the snipping tool or any other screenshot method as it is creating pixellised images (Snipping tool is limited to what is visible on one's screen).
Sorry for having been unclear.
My idea was more to get a printscreen with 1:1 composer rendering quality.
One good example of adjustable snipping tool is the option "take a snapshot" available in Adobe pdf reader (one can select more than what is visible on screen).

Comment: Isn't that exactly what happens when you export as an image?

Comment: Yes it is, but as I mentioned above I would like to avoid saving draft images on my computer and also do the long process of exporting image / going to the folder / opening image / copying / inserting in the report or the presentation I an working on. If someone think about creating  a " take a snapshot" option with QGIS I would be interested.